# Can the Photon Barrier Block Ultimates?

Tags: overwatch

Symmetra recently received some tender love and care for her kit, and this TLC added the new Photon Barrier ability. On a 10 second cooldown with 1000 health, this thing is pretty powerful. However, it's quite small in size.

Can this shield be used to block certain ultimates as other shields (Reinhardt and Winston) do? Can Reinhardt ***HAMMER DOWN!*** through it? Can D.VA truly ***NERF THIS!!!*** through the Photon Barrier?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It has the exact same behavior as Reinhardt's shield and Winston's bubble shield (and any other energy powered shield for that matter) so yes it should block both of those ults, although Earthshatter could go through the shield if it's not touching the ground (same as if Reinhardt is looking up).

Comment: Yes Zarya's Shield acts this way too. Protecting people behind her

Comment: Also, any ultimates that do enough damage will destroy the shield (such as D.Va's Self Destruct) and continue through it with sustained damage (such as Pharah's Rocket Barrage)

Comment: It's not identical in every situation actually, it's not destroyed by a Sombra EMP

Answer (score 6):

Yes, Symmetra's Photon Barrier acts like Reinhardt's and Winston's barriers, and will block anything those two barriers block. Specifically, it will block Earthshatter if it's touching the ground, and will block Self-destruct if you're fully covered by it.